# Javascript replace a div's content with a function when active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a function and some related jquery to work properly. I have a shopping cart that I am trying to display the number of items in the cart. Here is my basic mark-up so far.

html

```
<p>Your <a href="/cart.php">Shopping Cart:</a></span>
now has <span id="cartText">0 items</span></p>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var itms = '%%GLOBAL_CartItems%%';
   jQuery("#cartText").html( itms );

 });

</script>
```

The function I have of `%%GLOBAL_CartItems%%` tells how many items are in the cart but only when there is 1 or more so I wrote `0 items` in a div that I want the `%%GLOBAL_CartItems%%` function to replace once an item goes in the cart. I know what I have so far isn't right but on the right track I believe. This is on a BigCommerce based website if anyone is curious. Any Ideas?

Comment: you tagged this question under jquery and javascript but im wondering, what is that %%GLOBAL_CartItems%% about? that's not a jquery's function syntax i reckon

Comment: No it is not but the rest of it is, as I mentioned it is a custom function native to BigCommerce

Comment: How does your browser know the value of %%GLOBAL_CartItems%%. will some code of yours replace this with something? if not then the string %%GLOBAL_CartItems%% will be added in your 'cartText' span

Comment: If their are no items in the cart then the %%GLOBAL_CartItems%% string is inactive so it should show whats in my span, once it becomes active it will replace whats in the div. This is assuming I get the jQuery right first...any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution

```
 <div style="display:none;" id="CartContent">
 %%Panel.SideCartContents%% 
</div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   var itms = '%%GLOBAL_CartItems%%'; 
   var cartHTML   = jQuery("#CartContent").html();
   var cartAmount = jQuery(cartHTML).find("#tot strong").html();
   jQuery("#cartText").html( itms + ' - ' + cartAmount );

 });

</script>

<span id="cartText">Cart Empty - $0</span>
```

Then on my shopping cart file I put this:

```
<span id="tot">%%LNG_SideCartTotalCost%%</span>
```

This then displayed Cart Empty - $0 until an item went in the cart then it put in the info and replaced the div contents